# sql insert - breaking mysteriously

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

this is my code:

```
echo "total row anzahl: " . mysql_num_rows($new_entries) . "<br />";   //=>100
//for each row..
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($new_entries)){
$anzeigen_id = $row[0];    //text
$firma_id = $row[1];       //firma_id
//XML reading
$xml_filename = "xml/".$anzeigen_id.".xml";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($xml_filename);
$value = $dom->getElementsByTagName('FormattedPositionDescription');
foreach($value as $v){
    $text = $v->getElementsByTagName('Value');
    foreach($text as $t){
    $anzeige_txt = $t->nodeValue;
    $anzeige_txt = utf8_decode($anzeige_txt);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO joinvision_anzeige (`firmen_id`,`anzeige_id`,`anzeige_txt`) VALUES ('$firma_id','$anzeigen_id','$anzeige_txt')";
       $sql_inserted = mysql_query($sql);
       echo "inserted<br />";
     }
   }
 }
```

`$new_entries` is really 100, which means, i should be able to insert 100 items at once, but it is adding only 30. can someone tell me why?

the `inserted` message is coming really 100 times. but the data isnot inserted 100 times, but only 30 times, somewhere it is breaking.

Comment: doesnot it depend on this opening xml files?

Comment: Could you please show us the table schema as well?

Comment: check how many values you are getting in $value of your for loop

Comment: ``inserted`` message is coming 100 times, which means value is really coming 100 times as i wished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of check points:

1. Check if an xml file with `$anzeigen_id`.xml exists for all id's.
2. See if you have a `UNIQUE` key on `anzeige_id` or `firmen_id` or any such combination.

If both are not the issue, you can echo all the nodeValues and see if they are getting proper values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my Bad! the phpmyadmin was showing only 30 out of 100 :))). sorry!!

Comment: Oops!! Happens to every one of us :).